# How to Pin a Message in Discord

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot for a small server that I am in, and I want it to pin a certain message to the channel that it was sent in. I have done a few bots before, but it seems that the syntax has changed since I last used it, and code that I was going to reuse no longer works. I have managed to get around some of those changes (like the intents,) but when I try to check for a sent message, it just does nothing. My current code

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const { token } = require("./config.json");

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on("message", (msg) => {
  if (msg.content == "something goes here") {
    msg.pin()
  }
});

client.login(token);
```

I have tried supplementing `messageCreate` for `message` like I have seen a few people recommend, but it still seems to do nothing. Even changing the `msg.pin()` to `console.log(msg)` still shows nothing in the console

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (msg) => {
  if (msg.content == "something goes here") {
    console.log(msg)
  }
});
```

I do have the privileged intent toggle enabled, so I don't think that that is the problem
[[privileged toggles]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdjlA.png)

Does anybody know what the problem here is, and how I could fix it? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have not enabled the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent in your client so you need to add that by doing this:

```js
const client = new Client({ 
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ] 
});
```

Other than that, the `.pin()` function is still there and there is no change in it. You can provide a reason as well. The `.pin()` function also returns a promise, so you will have to use `.then()` or `await`, so your final code might look like this:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const { token } = require("./config.json");

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on("message", (msg) => {
  if (msg.content == "something goes here") {
    msg.pin().then(() => console.log)
  }
});

client.login(token);
```

You can learn more about the `.pin()` function here => [pin | discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=pin)

Answer (score 0):

**For Discord.js v13 use the following:**

```js
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const { token } = require("./config.json");

const client = new Client({
  intents: new Intents(32767)
});

client.login(token)

client.on("message", (ctx) => {
  if (ctx.content == "something goes here") {
    ctx.pin(ctx.id, "Pinned")
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).